# Cannot connect to Sql server from remotely

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a website developed using Visual studio 2012 as front end and SQL Server 2012 as back end it gives an "Timeout expired error". when I do any operation related to database it gives server timeout error.

website is hosted on godaddy server However I am also not able to connect SQL server from remotely and also form my website. it gives an error like this "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)"

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks & Regards
Fakhruddin Bharmal

Comment: Please post some code of what you tried...

Comment: I have written simple connection string in web.config file.
I try to connect SQL from remotely but it gives below error.
"A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)"